# How to judge if 4 paralleled "require" callbacks all finished?

Tags: javascript, callback, requirejs, require

I have some javascript codes as following:

```
require([url0],f0);
require([url1],f1);
require([url2],f2);
require([url3],f3);
```

`f0`,`f1`,`f2`, and `f3` are four functions.
Now I have another line of instruction. I want to execute it after all the four functions have finished execution. Where should I put the instruction, or should I change the structure of the existing codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own function that takes multiple arguments and calls a callback when they are all loaded:

```
function requireMulti(data, doneFn) {
    var numRemaining = data.length;
    data.forEach(function(val, index) {        
        require([val.url], function() {
            --numRemaining;
            val.fn.apply(this, arguments);
            if (numRemaining === 0) {
                doneFn();
            }
        });
    });
}

// sample usage
requireMulti([
    {url: url0, fn: f0},
    {url: url1, fn: f1},
    {url: url2, fn: f2},
    {url: url3, fn: f3},
  ], function() {
    // everything is done here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider taking a counter which initial value is 4 and a callback, wrapped in a class.

```
function CountDown(c, f) {
    this.counter = c;
    this.func = f;
    this.dec = function () {
        this.counter--;
        if (!this.counter) {
            this.func();
        }
    }
}

var counter = new CountDown(4, function () { alert('got all 4'); });
```

In all functions of `f0` ... `f3`, you can include a snippet like

```
function f0() {
    // code
    counter.dec();
}
```

Comment: the callback `this.func` is only executed if all four callbacks are finished, so the trigger is `counter.dec()`.

Comment: Oh I see, you suggest modifying code, instead of solving the problem outside. Okay, sorry